# Me sale error en el editor cuando intento usar módulos creado por mi. Si funciona cuando lo pruebo, pero el error sigue apareciendo

Tags: python, python-3.x, funciones, modulos

[image: La primera imagen es el modulo creado]

Estoy aprendiendo a usar módulos, me sale esto  cada que intento usar uno (creado por mi). Sí puedo usar el modulo, pero el error sigue estando ahí (el error solo aparece en el editor, mas no en la terminal).

[image: La segunda es donde lo intento usar]

Comment: No son errores, es solo una advertencia, si pasas el cursor te indicara el mensaje

Comment: Eso hice, pero no me ofrece ninguna solución. Solo aparece el mensaje "Unused import restar from wildcard importpylint(unused-wildcard-import)". Lo busque en Google pero no encuentro nada

Comment: Por favor, para la próxima pregunta incluye el código en vez de insertar imágenes del editor. Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**basico.py**

```
def sumar(a, b):
    return a + b

def restar(a, b):
    return a - b

def multiplicar(a, b):
    return a * b

def dividir(a, b):
    if b != 0:
        return a / b
    else:
        return "El segundo valor ha de ser distinto de 0"
```

**pruebas.py**

Si `basico.py` y `pruebas.py` están en la misma carpeta no es necesario indicar `calculos.basico`, puedes simplemente escribir `basico`.

```
from basico import sumar

print(sumar(2, 3))
```

**Resultado de ejecutar pruebas.py**

```
5
```

**Explicación**

Tu código está bien, no tienes ningún error, simplemente el editor de código te indica que estás importando `sumar`, `restar`, `multiplicar` y `dividir` de `basico.py`. Y solo estás usando `sumar` en `pruebas.py`.

`Unused import restar from wildcard importpylint(unused-wildcard-import)` te indica que estás importando `restar` pero no lo usas. Lo mismo con `multiplicar` y `dividir`.

Si solo quieres usar `sumar` y quieres que desaparezca la sugerencia del editor, escribe en `pruebas.py` lo siguiente: `from basico import sumar`

De todas formas, puedes importar todo, como ya estás haciendo, por si más tarde necesitas usar una función diferente: `from basico import *`. Simplemente ignora la advertencia del editor.